# Jsoup: find elements without id in html

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm new to Jsoup and I'm trying to parse an html-file to find all the elements without an id. Until now I only have this code snippet:

```
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, null);
        for (Element el : doc.getAllElements()) {
            hasId = el.hasAttr("id");
            if (!hasId) {
                idList.add(el.tagName());
            } else {
                log.info("id:" + el.attr("id"));
            }
        }
```

The elements with an id are found correctly. My problem is that I only want to scan the start elements if they have an id. Can I handle this with Jsoup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly, but I think you just want to select all elements that don't have an `id` attribute. If so, this should work:

```
doc.select("*:not([id])")
```

There's a [full list of selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) on the jsoup website.

***Update:***

Here's a full example:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;

public class Soup {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"> <tr> <td class=\"reportheader\" align=\"left\" nowrap width=\"720\">Outside my Dreams</td> </tr> </table>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(data);
    StringBuilder tags = new StringBuilder();
    for (Element el : doc.select("body *:not([id])")) {
      tags.append(el.tagName());
      tags.append(' ');
    }
    System.out.println(tags);
  }
}
```

Running the above on my machine gives me this output: **`table tbody tr td`**

Notice that I changed the query slightly: `"body *:not([id])"`. Adding `body` at the front excludes the `<html><title></title><body> ... </body></html>` that Jsoup automatically adds when parsing the partial document in the `data` string.

Comment: thx for your answer, but what i ment was; let's say we have this code: <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> <tr> <td class="reportheader" align="left" nowrap width="720">Outside my Dreams</td> </tr> </table>[/code] and i want to exclude all the end-tags (e.g. </td>, </tr>,</table...) from the search. how can i handle this. with combined selectors or is there another way?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm just not understanding you, or if you're just really confused. The end tags are never included as `Element`s in the result. You only see end tags in the output from `.toString()` so that you can see the nesting clearly. End tags are not not really elements—they just denote the end of an element. You can see this clearly by the output in the example I added above.

Comment: thx a lot four your help! i'm starting to understand the selector-syntax. will try to get more familiar with it during next days.